# g++ error while compiling C++ application that used Mono API

Tags: gcc, mono, g++, static-linking

I am compiling my C++ application and want to link it to mono. I am using OpenSusE. I have install mono-complete and glibc-devel-static packages. I am compiling as below -

```
$>g++ --static monoapp.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono` -I /usr/include/mono-2.0
/tmp/ccGfpBjX.o: In function `Launch(char const*, char const*, int, char const* const*, char const*)':
monoapp.cpp:(.text+0x23e): undefined reference to `mono_set_dirs'
monoapp.cpp:(.text+0x24f): undefined reference to `mono_jit_init_version'
monoapp.cpp:(.text+0x28b): undefined reference to `mono_domain_assembly_open'
monoapp.cpp:(.text+0x2c2): undefined reference to `mono_jit_exec'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

UPDATE 1 - I tried giving -lmono to linker but it complains about -lmono not found. Below is output of locate command.

```
$>locate libmono
/usr/lib64/libmono-2.0.a
/usr/lib64/libmono-2.0.so
/usr/lib64/libmono-2.0.so.1
/usr/lib64/libmono-2.0.so.1.0.0
```

Above output clearly shows that libmono is present.

UPDATE -2 Output of pkg-config is empty

```
$>pkg-config --cflags --libs mono

$>
```

UPDATE -3- I tried setting up PKG_CONFIG_PATH so that it can find mono.pc file but still it did not work

Please help.

Thanks,
Omky

Comment: Try -lmono-2.0 or create symlink for libmono.a pointing to libmono-2.0.a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by providing full path to static lib as -

g++ --static monoapp.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono` -I /usr/include/mono-2.0 -L /usr/lib64/ -lmono